# Calculate average of specified range of values in pandas column and store as another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, average

I can calculate the average in a for loop but that **doesn't** seem an efficient solution. So consider the following DataFrame:

```
Index Numbers
    1      12
    2      19
    3      47
    4      78
    5      32
    6      63
    7      89
```

I want to calculate the ***average of every number after the 4th value for the above four values*** and store it in an adjacent column. So the expected **output** is:

```
Index Numbers Average
    1      12       
    2      19       
    3      47
    4      78      39
    5      32      44
    6      63      55
    7      89    65.5
```

So average of first four numbers i.e. Index (1 to 4) is 39, next (2 to 5) is 44 and so on. Is there an efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html) with `mean`:

```
df['Average'] = df['Numbers'].rolling(4).mean()
print (df)
   Index  Numbers  Average
0      1       12      NaN
1      2       19      NaN
2      3       47      NaN
3      4       78     39.0
4      5       32     44.0
5      6       63     55.0
6      7       89     65.5
```

Possible functions implemented for `rolling`:

[`Rolling.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.count.html)
[`Rolling.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.sum.html)
[`Rolling.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean.html)
[`Rolling.median`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.median.html)
[`Rolling.var`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.var.html)
[`Rolling.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.std.html)
[`Rolling.min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.min.html)
[`Rolling.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.max.html)
[`Rolling.corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.corr.html)
[`Rolling.cov`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.cov.html)
[`Rolling.skew`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.skew.html)
[`Rolling.kurt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.kurt.html)
[`Rolling.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html)
[`Rolling.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.aggregate.html)
[`Rolling.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.quantile.html)

Comment: That worked! Thank you. So I can use rolling with other functions too?

Comment: Hey, one last question, what if I need to do this, Take Average at index 4 perform some calculation but store at index 5 and do the same for the rest. Using previous value... Example (39.0 * 2) / 4 store the output at index 5 then do for 44.0 and so on.

Comment: @YashGhorpade - hmmm, is possible save output to same index first and then use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) ?